# Bootstrap select custom dynamic options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) and I encounter a problem when I want to add dynamic options using Javascript. The list is always empty. When I switch back to using HTML select the following Javascript code works perfectly.

HTML:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-lg btn-list-author" 
id="author-list" data-live-search="true" title="Select Author"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
readDataFromGit('https://api.github.com/repos/' + repolink + '/contributors', function(text){
         data = JSON.parse(text);
         $.each(data, function(i, v) {
         alert(v.login);
         var ul = document.getElementById("author-list");
         var li = document.createElement("option");
         var linkText = document.createTextNode(v.login);
         li.appendChild(linkText);
         ul.appendChild(li);
     })
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With **bootstrap-select** you need to call the refresh method of the select-picker after you add new options.

Excerpt from [bootstrap-select `refresh` Documentation](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh):

> `.selectpicker('refresh')`
>
> To programmatically update a select with JavaScript, first manipulate
>   the select, then use the refresh method to update the UI to match the
>   new state. This is necessary when removing or adding options, or when
>   disabling/enabling a select via JavaScript.

**Untested Example Using Your Original Code:**

```
readDataFromGit('https://api.github.com/repos/' + repolink + '/contributors', function(text) {
    data = JSON.parse(text);
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        alert(v.login);
        var ul = document.getElementById("author-list");
        var li = document.createElement("option");
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(v.login);
        li.appendChild(linkText);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    })

    // Example call of 'refresh'
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

This lets bootstrap-select know of the data changes to the `select` element so it can redraw it's contents.

**Working Example (with a modified version of your code)**

[Working Codepen with some modifications](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjLZey?editors=0010)

Codepen Code:

```
// Had to create some stubs to replace missing code.
var repolink = 'silviomoreto/bootstrap-select';

function readDataFromGit (url, callback) {
  $.get(url, callback);
}
//End of stubs


  readDataFromGit('https://api.github.com/repos/' + repolink + '/contributors', function(text) {
      data = text; // Changed this because my stub is already returning parsed JSON.
      var ul = document.getElementById("author-list"); // moved this out of the loop for a bit of performance improvement (not relevant to the solution.)

      $.each(data, function(i, v) {
          var li = document.createElement("option");
          var linkText = document.createTextNode(v.login);
          li.appendChild(linkText);
          ul.appendChild(li);
      })

      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
  });
```

Comment: Very well-explained. Thank you!

Comment: Ohhhh... God, I spent one day for this `'refresh'` parameter for selectpicker. Nowhere is written that if you add options dynamically you must call refresh in the selectpicker method. Thank you very much +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dynamic drop-down menu with grouped options from a data array:

```js
// Example data Array list
namespace_list = [
    ['test1-c1', 'test2-c1', 'test3-c1', 'test4-c1', 'test5-c1', 'test6-c1'],
    ['test1-c2', 'test2-c2', 'test3-c2', 'test4-c2', 'test5-c2', 'test6-c2']
]


$('#pod_dropdown').selectpicker();

// Selecting selectpicker dropdown
select = document.getElementById('pod_dropdown');

for (let namespace of namespace_list) {

    // Generating group name
    namespace_name = namespace[0].slice(6, 8)+'-title'

    // Creating the optiongroup

    var optgroup = document.createElement('optgroup');
    optgroup.id = namespace_name;
    optgroup.label = namespace_name
    // Appending optiongroup to the dropdown
    select.appendChild(optgroup);

    // Selecting the optiongroup 
    optiongroup = document.getElementById(namespace_name);

    for (let pod of namespace) {

        // Creating the options of the optiongroup 
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = pod;
        opt.innerHTML = pod;
        // Appending the option to the optiongroup
        optiongroup.appendChild(opt);

    }

}
// Refresh the dropdwon menu
$('#pod_dropdown').selectpicker("refresh");



// Getting the value after selecting it in the UI and unselect the dropdown

function filterpod() {
    let pod = $('#pod_dropdown').val().toString();
    console.log(pod)

}
```

```html
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- multi select dropdown -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Creatting the dropdown -->
    <select id="pod_dropdown" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-sm" multiple data-live-search="true" data-width="auto"></select>
    
    <!-- Calling the function filterpod when hide dropdown after select option -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#pod_dropdown').on('hide.bs.select', function(e) {filterpod();});
    </script>
```